# Flutter - CustomScrollView how to listen sliver's positon

Tags: flutter, dart, uiscrollview, scrollview

This is my page structure:

```
CustomScrollView(
     SliverToBoxAdapter(),
     SliverPersistentHeader(pinned:true, Row(children:[tab_A, tab_B ,tab_C])),
     SliverToBoxAdapter(A), // A SliverToBoxAdapter
     SliverToBoxAdapter(B), // B SliverToBoxAdapter
     SliverToBoxAdapter(C), // C SliverToBoxAdapter
)
```

My requirement is :
I scroll CustomScrollView. When A SliverToBoxAdapter is visible, tab_A is highlighted, When B SliverToBoxAdapter is visible and A SliverToBoxAdapter is invisible, tab_B is highlighted and so on...

I know scrollController can listen scroll position. But A, B, C SliverToBoxAdapter’s height are uncertain.Calculations are a bit complicated. 
Any other approaches?

Comment: @Ahmed Hussein please share your idea

Comment: use [RenderBox.size](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox/size.html) property to calculate certain height - you need `GlobalKey` to get `RenderBox`

Comment: @pskink thank you, any other methods?